# Google Ecommerce tracking not firing via GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I was trying to add Google Analytic eCommerce tracking in a website via Google tag manager. For this I have created layer just above Google tag Manager iframe just below  tag.

Since we are hosting our website in volusion. There order specific variables are listed below

Order Array Contents

```
Order[0] = Order ID
Order[1] = Unused
Order[2] = Payment Amount
Order[3] = Affiliate Commissionable Value
Order[4] = Sales Tax
Order[5] = Total Shipping Cost
Order[6] = Billing City
Order[7] = Billing State
Order[8] = Billing Country
Order[9] = Email Address
```

OrderDetails Array Contents

```
OrderDetails[X][0] = Order ID
OrderDetails[X][1] = Order Detail ID
OrderDetails[X][2] = Product Code
OrderDetails[X][3] = Product Name
OrderDetails[X][5] = Product Price
OrderDetails[X][6] = Quantity
```

The datalayer I have created is as below

```
<script>
dataLayer = [{
"transactionId" : "Order[0]",
"transactionAffiliation" : "Order[3]",
"transactionTotal" : "Order[2]",
"transactionShipping" : "Order[5]",
"transactionTax" : "Order[4]",
"transactionProducts" : [{
"name" : "OrderDetails[X][3]",
"sku" : "OrderDetails[X][2]",
"price" : "OrderDetails[X][5]",
"quantity" : "OrderDetails[X][6]"
}]
}];
</script>
```

Still it is not firing the value to Google Analytics for eCommerce tracking. Can anyone help me and let me know why it is not working

Thanks,,

Thanveer

Comment: You waited 24 hours to see if the data showed up on the standard reports?

Comment: Yes, actually I waited more than that!//
Did you mean the layer I created are fine?

Comment: Does "not fire" mean the tag is not fired in GTM (in that case we'd need the rules for that tag to see what is wrong) or is the tag fired but the data does not arrive in Analytics (have you tried a debugger to see what is actually sent ?) ?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52569504/rule%20for%20ga.PNG

This is the rule for that particular tag.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52569504/fired.PNG

And this what I can see in the debugger for that tag which fired!!

Comment: Not the actual problem but still something you should fix: You have quotation marks around your javascript variables. That means you do not transmit the variable values but literal strings (e.g. "OrderDetails[X][6]") which is most certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your code like below:

```
<script>
    dataLayer = [{
    "transactionId" : Order[0],
    "transactionAffiliation" : Order[3],
    "transactionTotal" : Order[2],
    "transactionShipping" : Order[5],
    "transactionTax" : Order[4],
    "transactionProducts" : [{
    "name" : OrderDetails[X][3],
    "sku" : OrderDetails[X][2],
    "price" : OrderDetails[X][5],
    "quantity" : OrderDetails[X][6]
    }]
    }];
</script>
```

Put all array values without double quote. Make sure you are properly replacing value of `X` in array `OrderDetails[X][2]`. Probably use for loop for more items within an order details.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening in the shopping cart or at purchase, then your dataLayer is missing some values.

Here's the correct way to do it:

```
window.dataLayer.push({
"event" : "checkout",
"ecommerce" : {
    "checkout" : {
        "actionField" : {
            "id" : "Order[0]",
            "step" : "1"},
            "affiliation" : "Order[3]",
            "subtotal" : "Order[2]",
            "shipping" : "Order[5]",
            "tax" : "Order[4]",
            "products" : [{
                "name" : "OrderDetails[X][3]",
                "sku" : "OrderDetails[X][2]",
                "price" : "OrderDetails[X][5]",
                "quantity" : "OrderDetails[X][6]"
                }]
            }
}});
```

The important thing here is the key value pair `"event":"checkout"` and `"ecommerce":"checkout"`.

If you have more than one checkout step, the actionField takes the `"step":"n"` key value pair where n is the step number (make sure to set your checkout funnel in the analytics admin section).

If this is the final step that leads to a transaction, then the event is `transaction` and the `ecommerce` action is `purchase`.

Edit: actually, I'm not too sure if the `event` key value pair is necessary. I do know the `ecommerce` key value pair is absolutely essential.